# socket.io websocket connection invalid (latest chrome)

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

After installing node.js, I followed this [tutorial](http://psitsmike.com/2011/09/node-js-and-socket-io-chat-tutorial/) to start a simple chat server. It was very easy to setup and is working, but I have noticed two problems:

1.) I am getting this warning from socket.io

```
info  - socket.io started
debug - served static /socket.io.js
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized 1385647068766475337
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/1385647068766475337
debug - set heartbeat interval for client 1385647068766475337
warn  - websocket connection invalid
```

This doesn't make sense to me because I didn't touch anything with socket.io and I am using the latest chrome version (23) which I know supports websockets (I am able to successfully connect to them with PHP-Websockets). It continues to use XHR instead, but I am really interested in getting the Websocket functionality working.

2.) When I go to localhost:8080 to connect to the chat server, it takes around 7-8 seconds for it to prompt me for my name and actually connect me to the server. I have a feeling this may be because it is reverting to XHR, but I don't really know much about it so I can't say. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. I'm using Chrome 24.

Comment: where does the warning even come from (code) ? I couldn't find it in the library. "websocket connection invalid"

Answer (score 2):

I saw this behaviour when using an older version of socket.io with later chrome builds (and other browsers also). It would timeout then fallback to xhr polling. To check your version of the socket.io library you are using, at your shell (linux/unix) type:

```
npm ls| grep socket.io
```

And it should tell you the version. The latest at this time is 0.9.13, which works.

If you are running the tutorial from http://psitsmike.com note that the package.json file hardcodes an older version of socket.io which doesn't work with the latest browsers.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing similar issues.

Your case -

- Try deleting your cookies, sometimes the xhr-polling option once connected successfully is saved to cookies and reused every next time. [Similar question answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4453873/2103202)
- Also `debug - served static /socket.io.js` sometimes come when the socket.io file is referred incorrectly inside the html or jade template file. Try correcting the script src link in case it wrong. It should be something like - `var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');` OR you can also try removing the link all together like this - `var socket = io.connect();`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. this might be old. but My setup is on digitalocean. what happens is that usually people who run node apps on one server use nginx for the port listen and node under its own dedicated port. nginx did not forward the websocket port to the node, only port 80 which nodejs was not initialised to begin with.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html

You need to make sure your nginx is configured properly for this.

I just added the port to the io.connect directly connecting to the node server and avoiding nginx.