# Websocket not working with socket.io in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket, socket.io

My app is working fine in localhost with socket.io using websockets and xhr-polling and it's working with xhr-polling in heroku, but since heroku provided support for websocket I can´t make it work using websockets.

My Chrome console shows this message:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://<myherokuapp>.herokuapp.com/socket.io/1/websocket/HBWE2BFvHahlSWk5ppHP' failed: Unexpected response code: 503
```

I already enabled websocket labs.

Is there any working example of websocket using socket.io?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same problem and just fixed it by **reactivating the websockets on my app** on heroku. 
It had just randomly switched over to XHR polling for some reason.

I used this command from heroku's site (@ https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-labs-websockets) to reactivate it:

> `heroku labs:enable websockets -a myapp`

I then restarted my server by pushing to heroku and having it rebuild (or using: `heroku restart`).

I also have a working copy of a very basic socket.io chat application (written by Smitha Milli) running at: http://calm-gorge-8474.herokuapp.com/ that you can test.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I also found this answer, which also provides more clarity on how XHR polling could just randomly be activated, when randomly saved to cookies: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19680457/2728686

Comment: @Igor It's a pleasure, glad I could help!

Comment: "I then restarted my server by pushing to heroku and having it rebuild." You can restart by doing `heroku restart`

Comment: @AmpT even your website `calm` is showing xhr-polling in my browser

Comment: For use with simpleWebRTC I had to explicitly set port number 80 in url like so: `http://myserver.herokuapp.com:80`

Comment: "heroku labs:enable" was a good answer at the time, but it no longer works, nor is it necessary, since websockets is no longer a lab feature on Heroku, but is enabled by default.