# Nodejs+socket.io : Prevent fallback to xhr-polling after reconnect to worker process (cluster module)

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cluster-computing

I am using [cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module to fork a new worker every time a worker process dies. My node server and client communicate over websockets (socket.io). What I see is that after a worker dies and the client connects to a new worker process, the communication occasionally falls back to xhr-polling.

So before a worker dies: websockets.

After a worker dies: xhr-polling (sometimes. But why ?. I do a see handshake errors upon reconnect when this happens)

I have configured the transport option to use 'websocket' only, but this does not seem to help.

I also tried configuring the parameters mentioned below, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420393/nodejs-socket-io-chrome-not-loading-with-websockets). But this did not help either. I still see occasional fallback to xhr-polling after a reconnect to a new worker.

- tryTransportsOnConnectTimeout - default value is true
- rememberTransport - default value is true

Any idea how I can force the use websockets only ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure that you use the word ``transports`` on the server and not ``transport``, such as this: ``io.set('transports', ['websocket']);``

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure TimeOut and Transports in Socket.IO 1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685198/configure-timeout-and-transports-in-socket-io-1-0)