# Configure TimeOut and Transports in Socket.IO 1.0

Tags: node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

In old versions of Socket.IO (< 0.9), I configured "close timeout" and "transports" this way:

```
io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]);
io.set("close timeout", 3);
```

But now, the command `io.set` has been deprecated. How do I define `close timeout` and `transports`?

When I use the old version this message appears:

> Option close timeout is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation here: http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#configuration-differences

Basically, you just have to set those when you initialize the server:

```
var socket = require('socket.io')({
  // options go here
});
```

Comment: but how to configure socket if it's attached to http or express server ?