# Transport Settings in Socket.IO 1.4.x

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku, socket.io, deployd

I have been tinkering with **deployd** on Heroku using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/facultymatt/5373247) as a starting point:

- https://gist.github.com/facultymatt/5373247

Line 20 of that `server.js` tries to set transports for socket.io  like so:

```js
server.sockets.manager.settings.transports = ["xhr-polling"];
```

But encounters this error:

> Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined.

From research so far it seems this approach is deprecated in socket.io 1.4.5.   However, if that's so I am not clear on how I should address this setting.

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685198/configure-timeout-and-transports-in-socket-io-1-0). But differs in that I seek to change the settings once socket.io is already constructed by and attached to an instance of deployd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it on creation:

```
var server = deployd({
    socketIo: {
        options: { transports : ['xhr-polling'] }
    }
});
```

Or if you can't do that, change it runtime (this is a hack):

```
server.sockets.server.eio.transports = ['xhr-polling'];
```

(This is still supported for backwards compatibility:)

```
server.sockets.server.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);
```

Comment: The third option, backwards compatibility, worked so I am back in business. I will try your other two suggestions when I have time to come back to it. I'll update this question with the results when I have them.  

Thanks for your help