# Flask-SocketIO server using polling instead of websockets

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm working on a Flask-SocketIO server that works just fine.

However, I'm getting lots of requests like this in my server log:

`"GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LBS1TQt HTTP/1.1"`

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
import json

def load_config():
    # configuration
    return json.load(open('/etc/geekdj/config.json'))

config = load_config()

geekdj = Flask(__name__)

geekdj.config["DEBUG"] = config["debug"]
geekdj.config["SECRET_KEY"] = config["secret_key"]
geekdj.config.from_envvar("FLASKR_SETTINGS", silent=True)

socketio = SocketIO(geekdj)

@geekdj.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

# SocketIO functions

@socketio.on('connect')
def chat_connect():
    print ('connected')

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def chat_disconnect():
    print ("Client disconnected")

@socketio.on('broadcast')
def chat_broadcast(message):
    print ("test")
    emit("chat", {'data': message['data']})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(geekdj, port=8000)
```

and the JS in `index.html`:

```
<script src="//cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        // the socket.io documentation recommends sending an explicit package upon connection
        // this is specially important when using the global namespace
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');

        socket.on('connection', function(socket) {
            socket.emit('foo', {foo: "bar"});
            socket.join("test");
        });

        socket.on('joined', function(data) {
            console.log('Joined room!');
            console.log(data["room"]);
        });
     });
```

I'd prefer to be using actual Websockets if possible, does anyone know why SocketIO is falling back on polling?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution [in this other Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420393/nodejs-socket-io-chrome-not-loading-with-websockets).

It turns out that SocketIO sets a cookie with the most recent connection type that worked. In my case, it was polling.

So, I changed the SocketIO connect statement in my JS from

`var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');`

to

`var socket = io.connect(null, {port: 8000, rememberTransport: false});`

and now there is activity in the websockets type under the Network tab in the Chrome developer tools (which there wasn't previously):

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Did the first answer work? If so, you should accept it. If not, post your requirements.txt please.

I had the same problem and found the resolution by fully absorbing the documentation page:

> The asynchronous services that this package relies on can be selected
>   among three choices:
>
> - eventlet is the best performant option, with support for long-polling    and WebSocket transports.
> - gevent is supported in a number of different configurations. The    long-polling transport is fully supported with the gevent package,
>     but unlike eventlet, gevent does not have native WebSocket support.
>     To add support for WebSocket there are currently two options.
>     Installing the gevent-websocket package adds WebSocket support to
>     gevent or one can use the uWSGI web server, which comes with
>     WebSocket functionality. The use of gevent is also a performant
>     option, but slightly lower than eventlet.
> - The Flask development server based on Werkzeug can be used as well,    with the caveat that it lacks the performance of the other two
>     options, so it should only be used to simplify the development
>     workflow. This option only supports the long-polling transport.

Basically, I didn't have evenlet nor gevent-websocket in my virtual environment. I installed eventlet, and transport upgrade to websocket was near instantaneous! Hope this helps.

Comment: How exactly did you use eventlet in order to enable socketio to work properly? Did you invoke `eventlet.monkey_patch()` or?

Comment: All i did was install it, the upgrade was automatic.

Comment: @jacob question regarding "This option only supports the long-polling transport."  Does setting the async_mode with "socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode=async_mode)" allow the websockets to be run?  Or does the flask-socketIO application run in

Comment: According to the documentation, valid async modes are "threading, eventlet, gevent and gevent_uwsgi". My understanding is the only way to get around long-polling is to not use the built in Flask development server.